# Multiple functions won't load with window.onload

Tags: javascript, function, date, time, onload

I know this question has been asked before many time, and has had many solutions, but for some reason I can't get it to work properly. People have said to use `<body onload="">`, but what I'm doing won't allow that. What I have is 4 areas that are powered by JavaScript to display certain things:

```
<div id="social-media"></div>
<div id="clock"></div>
<div id="date"></div>
<div id="copyright"></div>
```

I want all of these to load when the page loads. I found that everyone says to put all your `functions` inside 1 main `function` like so:

```
window.onload = function () {
 function TimeUpdate () {code-here};
 function CopyrightYear () {code-here};
 function DateUpdate () {code-here};
 function SocialMedia () {code-here};
}
```

But it won't work. Each will load if it's completely by itself, but not when grouped together, so I don't think I'll need to do that many revisions to the `functions`. I tried adding a name to the main function: `window.onload = function Text () {code-here}`, but it didn't work. I even tried rearranging the order of the `functions`, but that didn't do anything either. I'd like some help getting this fixed, and of possible a detailed explanation on the fixes. Thanks.

Here's the full code:

```
window.onload = function () {
 // Clock
 function TimeUpdate () {
  var now = new Date (), hours = now.getHours (), minutes = now.getMinutes (), seconds = now.getSeconds ();
  if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {var TimeOfDay = "PM";}
  else {var TimeOfDay = "AM";}
  if (hours > 12) {hours = hours - 12;}
  if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}
  if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
  if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
  var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay;
  var MyClock = document.getElementById ('clock');
  MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;
 };
 setInterval (function () {TimeUpdate ();}, 1000);

 // Copyright
 function CopyrightYear () {
  document.getElementById ("copyright").innerHTML = 'Copyright &copy; 20xx&ndash;20xx. All rights reserved.';
 };

 // Date
 function DateUpdate () {
  var date = new Date (), month = date.getMonth () +1, day = date.getDate (), year = date.getFullYear ();
  month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
  day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
  month = (month > 12) ? month - 12 : month;
  month = (month == 0) ? 12 : month;
  var TimeDisplay = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  document.getElementById ("date").innerHTML = TimeDisplay;
 };

 // Social Media
 function SocialMedia () {
  document.getElementById ("social-media").innerHTML = '<ul><li id="facebook"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="google-plus"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="linkedin"><a href="---"><br></a></li></ul>'
 };
}
```

Comment: I don't ever see you calling the functions `CopyrightYear`, `DateUpdate`, or `SocialMedia`.  Where do you call the functions to execute?

Comment: You have defined the functions `TimeUpdate` `CopyrightYear` `DateUpdate` and `SocialMedia`  within the `onload` function, thus within only the `onload` function scope. Any calls outside the `onload` function will not be able to see any of the functions.

Answer (score 1):

You never execute the functions.

JavaScript functions do not automatically get executed when they are hit by the interpreter, you have to call them after they are defined in order for something to happen.

For example:

```js
var num = 0;
function count() {
    num += 1;
    document.write(num);
    document.write('<br/>'); // New line.
}

count();
count();
count();
```

So in your case, if you want those functions to run, you will need to call them at the end of your `onload` function, like so:

```
CopyrightYear();
DateUpdate();
SocialMedia();
```

Comment: I did this (and added in TimeUpdate) but now only the time and copyright show. The other two are still blank.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle, where we can run your example.

Comment: Here it is. http://jsfiddle.net/L5pud8z6/. The words between the divs should vanish if things work properly.

Comment: You have a syntax error.  Change the comma at the end of `var CurrentTime` to a semi-colon.

Comment: Well I separated those 2 vars for this post and I guess I forgot the change it. But it still doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/L5pud8z6/1/

Comment: There was a fiddle option to change, and you still had to call the functions:  http://jsfiddle.net/L5pud8z6/3/

Answer (score 0):

Remove all these functions from the onload event handler, and just call them from there, and everything should work ok.

```js
 // Clock
 function TimeUpdate() {
   var now = new Date(),
     hours = now.getHours(),
     minutes = now.getMinutes(),
     seconds = now.getSeconds();
   if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {
     var TimeOfDay = "PM";
   } else {
     var TimeOfDay = "AM";
   }
   if (hours > 12) {
     hours = hours - 12;
   }
   if (seconds < 10) {
     seconds = "0" + seconds;
   }
   if (minutes < 10) {
     minutes = "0" + minutes;
   }
   if (hours < 10) {
     hours = "0" + hours;
   }
   var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay,
     var MyClock = document.getElementById('clock');
   MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;
 };

 // Copyright
 function CopyrightYear() {
   document.getElementById("copyright").innerHTML = 'Copyright &copy; 20xx&ndash;20xx. All rights reserved.';
 };

 // Date
 function DateUpdate() {
   var date = new Date(),
     month = date.getMonth() + 1,
     day = date.getDate(),
     year = date.getFullYear();
   month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
   day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
   month = (month > 12) ? month - 12 : month;
   month = (month == 0) ? 12 : month;
   var TimeDisplay = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
   document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = TimeDisplay;
 };

 // Social Media
 function SocialMedia() {
   document.getElementById("social-media").innerHTML = '<ul><li id="facebook"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="google-plus"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="linkedin"><a href="---"><br></a></li></ul>'
 };

 window.onload = function() {
   DateUpdate();
   setInterval(function() {
     TimeUpdate();
   }, 1000);
   CopyrightYear();
   SocialMedia();

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had it, you're just missing the calls to the functions...

```
window.onload = function () {
// Clock
 function TimeUpdate () {
  var now = new Date (), hours = now.getHours (), minutes = now.getMinutes (), seconds = now.getSeconds (),TimeOfDay = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {TimeOfDay = "PM";}
  else {TimeOfDay = "AM";}
  if (hours > 12) {hours = hours - 12;}
  if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds;}
  if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes;}
  if (hours < 10) {hours = "0" + hours;}
  var CurrentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + "&nbsp;" + TimeOfDay;
  var MyClock = document.getElementById ('clock');
  MyClock.innerHTML = CurrentTime;

  //Call CopyRight Function...
  CopyrightYear();

  //Call DateUpdate Function...
  DateUpdate();

  //Call SocialMedia Function...
  SocialMedia();


 };
 setInterval (function () {TimeUpdate ();}, 1000);

 // Copyright
 function CopyrightYear () {
  document.getElementById ("copyright").innerHTML = 'Copyright &copy; 20xx&ndash;20xx. All rights reserved.';
 };


 // Date
 function DateUpdate () {
  var date = new Date (), month = date.getMonth () +1, day = date.getDate (), year = date.getFullYear ();
  month = (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month;
  day = (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day;
  month = (month > 12) ? month - 12 : month;
  month = (month == 0) ? 12 : month;
  var TimeDisplay = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
  document.getElementById ("date").innerHTML = TimeDisplay;
 };


 // Social Media
 function SocialMedia () {
  document.getElementById ("social-media").innerHTML = '<ul><li id="facebook"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="google-plus"><a href="---"><br></a></li><li id="linkedin"><a href="---"><br></a></li></ul>'
 };


}
```

Comment: to test the functions and if they are working, remark out the first timer function and where it calls it right beneath it. Run it again and those other functions should kick off successfully. Let me know if that works and then we can rework the timer function

Comment: OK, I see a few things wrong with the TimeOfDay function. First, why do you need it? Second, the following is making TimeOfDay local to only exist within those curly braces.       if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24) {var TimeOfDay = "PM";}
  else {var TimeOfDay = "AM";}.           You need to set it up outside of that like you did for hours/minutes/seconds.

Comment: Changed above main code example I did to work with the timer. I have not checked the timer code.

Comment: `TimeOfDay` is for showing if it is AM or PM. So I need to have `if (hours >= 12 && hours < 24)` in their own seperate `if` statements?